# Knowing Happen in Every Martial's Battle

Tags: mixed-martial-arts

In every Martial Arts has their movement. Such as Kyukpa, Chireugi, Step One, Step Two, hit one, hit two, and anything. When a Martial Athlete make a movement, There will some of movement will possible to do by the victim or me.

And My question is How we know what is the next movement that will he do. If we know his belt and level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had done any reasonable amount of training then you would know the answer to your question.

There are a number of reasons why you cannot always know the next move:

- there can be many possible moves from a certain position
- you would be assuming that your opponent is predictable. I wouldn't make an assumption like that in a fight
- different schools even within the same style don't always teach the same thing
- you are predicating your desired answer on the opponent only training in one art/school, you are excluding everything else

It doesn't matter if you know his belt and level. The only way to definitively know (or narrow down the options) what the next move will be is to train with that person and get to know them and their style. Every practitioner is different (hint: did you ever wonder why they are called martial **arts**?). For your question to be answerable every practitioner would have to be a robot trained/programmed in the exact same way.

We can give you options on how to counter or avoid specific moves/techniques, but we cannot tell you with any certainty what the next move will be.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that information. But, i learn every movement of some martial such as taekwondo(yellow belt), silat(blue belt) and karate(green belt). I know about possible movement that will happend. There is not many movement. But the direction will victim do make the movement looks many. And now my question is, how we can know where the direction can he do. Where there are so many 1/2 *phi* r^2?

Comment: Sorry if i ask a very very crazy question. I can do something because i know the theory. And Math is something beautiful for me. Sorry for that